# Geometric meaning of this inequality $|\det(A)|\leq ||a_1||\cdot||a_2||...||a_n||$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was given this problem: Prove that $|\det(A)|\leq ||a_1||\cdot||a_2||...||a_n||$, where $A$ is an invertible matrix.

I have managed to prove it by myself (using QR decomomposition), but I can't see the geometric meaning of it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant of a matrix is equal to the signed area of the [parallelepipid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) formed by its column vectors. This inequality says that the parallelepipid has smaller area then a [hyperrectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) whose side lengths are $\|a_i\|$. It's easy to see in two dimensions because the parallelepipid is basically a squashed rectangle, so it must have smaller area.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's quite clear - I don't get now why I had to ask question about it when it's a really straightforward inequality :-) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

$\det A$ is the volume of the parallelipiped spanned by $a_i$. The inequality is saying that this volume is maximized by that of the $n$-dimensional box (i.e. right-angled corners) with side lengths $\|a_i\|$, which you can prove fairly easily by Cavalieri's principle from calculus.